# ¿Cómo insertar los resultados de un objeto glm en una tabla?

Tags: r, tablas, r-markdown

Deseo insertar los resultados que devuelve `summary(glm(*))` en una **tabla** para poder presentar los resultados de modo que sea más atractivo visualmente.

Sea el siguiente dataframe:

```
    SAP niv_est  edad  sexo
1     1       1    84     0
2     0       4    26     1
3     1       4    56     0
4     0       2    70     1
5     0       3    61     1
6     0       4    35     0
```

Queremos efectuar un modelo logit binomial y que nos muestre los resultados, así que:

`summary(glm(SAP ~   niv_est + edad + sexo,data = datos_duda, family = binomial(link = "logit")))`

Esto nos devuelve lo siguiente:

```
Call:
glm(formula = SAP ~ niv_est + edad + sexo, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = datos_duda, na.action = "na.omit")

Deviance Residuals: 
         1           2           3           4           5           6  
 5.662e-06  -2.110e-08   7.055e-06  -4.995e-06  -6.821e-06  -8.383e-06  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -190.502 748512.185       0        1
niv_est         21.404 112623.998       0        1
edad             2.309   7487.683       0        1
sexo           -39.042 130544.837       0        1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 7.6382e+00  on 5  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2.2359e-10  on 2  degrees of freedom
AIC: 8

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 24
```

Obviando los resultados de la estimación, lo que deseo es que me devuelva los resultados generados en la tabla `Coefficients` de un modo más atractivo y cómo visualmente, ya que tengo que **presentar estos resultados para mi TFG**. He intentado instertar este código en un archivo **R markdown** empleando la librería `printr`pero esto me devuelve la misma tabla que si no ejecutara `library(printr`. ¿alguna alternativa para no tener que pasar los datos a una tabla de forma manual empleando excel, por ejemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para generar una matriz similar a los datos de `Coefficients` simplemente podríamos hacer algo así:

```
s <- summary(glm(SAP ~   niv_est + edad + sexo,data = datos_duda, family = binomial(link = "logit")))
s$coefficients

              Estimate Std. Error       z value  Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -190.501935 748512.185 -0.0002545075 0.9997969
niv_est       21.403929 112623.998  0.0001900477 0.9998484
edad           2.308983   7487.683  0.0003083708 0.9997540
sexo         -39.041812 130544.837 -0.0002990682 0.9997614
```

Es decir, instanciamos un objeto de la clase `summary.glm` y extraemos de él la matriz correspondiente a los coeficientes. Esto es lo más sencillo, podríamos eventualmente regenerar la tabla directamente del modelo (hay datos suficientes para hacerlo), pero nos obligaría a hacer "ingeniería inversa" para reproducir lo que hace `summary()`. Por último, te puedo sugerir el paquete `broom` que muy útil para trabajar con modelos e integrarlos con el universo `tidyverse`:

```
library("broom")
modelo <- glm(SAP ~   niv_est + edad + sexo,data = datos_duda, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

tidy(modelo)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
  term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 (Intercept)  -191.     748512. -0.000255    1.00
2 niv_est        21.4    112624.  0.000190    1.00
3 edad            2.31     7488.  0.000308    1.00
4 sexo          -39.0    130545. -0.000299    1.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe un paquete llamado `stargazer` el cual convierte las salidas de tablas y modelos de regresión en formato latex, txt, word y html. Es un aproximación de presentación que se usa en papers.

```
library(stargazer)

# Lo tendría que usar de esta manera. 

regre<-glm(SAP ~ niv_est + edad + sexo,data = datos_duda, family = binomial(link ="logit"))

stargazer(regre, type="doc", out="word_regre.doc")
```

Tendrá en su directorio de trabajo un archivo word con la regresión de una forma muy estilizada.

Espero pueda servirle.

Puede usted colocar varios modelos en la función `stargazer`.

Comment: Cuando intento ejecutar `stargazer(regre, type="doc", out="word_regre.doc")` obtengo el siguiente error: `% Error: 'style' must be either 'latex' (default), 'html' or 'text.'`  ¿Alguna idea de por qué me da este error? tengo ya instalado latex en mi pc, así que no sé a que puede deberse el error.